# Change screen position in underscaled custom resolution on Windows

Tags: windows-10, resolution, projector

I'm trying to display a custom aspect ratio (32:9) on a projector that doesn't support custom resolutions. I've created a custom resolution on Windows 10 through Nvidia Control Panel at 3840 x 1080 with the "Adjust desktop size and position" set to "Aspect Ratio" but it centers the display and puts black bars top and bottom like this:

[Screen as it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVZw2.png)

What I'm looking to do is to move the position of the "desktop" from the middle to the top like this:

[Screen as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xs6b.png)

There are no controls on the projector to allow me to move the position of the image and it will only fit in this way. I'm at a loss for a software solution, does anyone know how to achieve this on Windows? And if not software is there a hardware solution?

Comment: What's wrong with using a resolution that the projector supports?

Comment: The projector only supports 16:9 and 4:3 aspect ratios. We're projecting onto a custom screen which is a wide 32:9. We're limited by throw distances and we can't move the projector further up or the screen any lower.